# App crashing on count and dialog box

Tags: java, android

i am using following code.

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
   {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
             displayAlertForRestart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            counter.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " sec");
        }

     }


   public void displayAlertForRestart()
   {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Restart?");
    builder.setTitle("Game Over");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,Level.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
      }  
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();

      }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
   }
```

LogCat error: Error at  `alert.show();`

```
36: E/AndroidRuntime(9829): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43cf1e38 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` or `pass your activity object` instead of `this in alertdialog constructor`

Comment: you cant use getApplicationContext() for a dialog plz remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your countdown is not finished, you must FIRST FINISH it before finishing the activity.

Try this, `myCount.cancel` when you finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
   {

   Context mContext;

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,Context context) 
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

            mContext=context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(Context context) 
        {
             displayAlertForRestart(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            counter.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " sec");
        }

     }


   public void displayAlertForRestart(Context context)
   {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Restart?");
    builder.setTitle("Game Over");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,Level.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
      }  
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();

      }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
   }
```

Comment: you might want to add `private` before `Context mContext;`

Comment: i don't get it, i am in the same activity. what will be the difference? Okay i try do it

Comment: if context is not proper then you will get this kind of exceptions

Comment: putting context on onfinish asks for removing override notation

Comment: use displayAlertForRestart(mContext);

Comment: it gave the same error. I HAVE checked that it won't happen when i call the activity. once activity is called and i restart the activity and time is up then this happenes.